# Transaction management with Spring and hibernate, using isolation_serializable

Tags: spring, transactions, hibernate-mapping, transaction-isolation

I am using Spring transaction management to control a application with hibernate, it uses two instance of threads to access concurrency database and modify one table. It is ensuring that the values are conserved. 
The table before is:

```
   quantidade_livro_id | quantidade | livro_id | tt 
  ---------------------+------------+----------+----
                     7 |        100 |        3 | as 
                     5 |        100 |        1 | as
                     6 |        100 |        2 | as
```

And the table after:

```
   quantidade_livro_id | quantidade | livro_id | tt 
  ---------------------+------------+----------+----
               7 |        100 |        3 | as
               5 |         50 |        1 | as
               6 |        150 |        2 | as
```

The main code start two threads:

```
        Servico t1 = new Servico();
        Servico t2 = new Servico();
        //transaction 1
        t1.setId1(5);
        t1.setValorTransacao(50);
        t1.setId2(6);
        //transaction 2     
        t2.setId1(5);   
        t2.setValorTransacao(100);
        t2.setId2(7);   

        //start transaction 1
        t1.start();
        //start transaction 2
        t2.start();
```

The class Servico is:

```
public void run() {
        executa();
    }


public void executa(){
    ApplicationContext appContext = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/config/BeanLocations.xml");

    livroQuantidadeBo = (LivroQuantBo)appContext.getBean("livroQuantBoProxy");
    try {
        livroQuantidadeBo.transacao(getId1(),getValorTransacao(),getId2());
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The class LivroQuantBoImpl have the method:

```
public void transacao(int id1,int valorTransferencia, int id2) throws RuntimeException{
    LivroQuantidade livroQ = livroQuantDao.find(id1);
    LivroQuantidade livroQ2 = livroQuantDao.find(id2);
    if(livroQ.getQuantidade() - valorTransferencia >= 0){
        livroQ.setQuantidade(livroQ.getQuantidade() - valorTransferencia);
        livroQ2.setQuantidade(valorTransferencia + livroQ2.getQuantidade());
        livroQuantDao.update(livroQ);
        livroQuantDao.update(livroQ2);
    }
}
```

And my Spring .conf is :

```
    <!--  DATASOURCE -->  
    <bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" 
             class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


    <!-- HIBERNATE -->

    <!-- Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" 
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
             <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
             <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
         </property>

         <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
               <value>hibernate/Livro.hbm.xml</value>
               <value>hibernate/LivroQuantidade.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
          </property>   

        </bean>

    <!-- TRANSAÇÃO  -->

    <bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
        <prop key="save">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="transacao">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
        <prop key="transacao">ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!-- BEANS -->
        <!-- Livro business object -->
       <bean id="livroBo" class="br.com.spring.bo.LivroBoImpl" >
            <property name="livroDao" ref="livroDao" />
            <property name="livroQuantBo" ref="livroQuantBo" />
       </bean>

       <!-- Livro Data Access Object -->
       <bean id="livroDao" class="br.com.spring.dao.LivroDaoImpl" >
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
       </bean>

        <!-- ProductQoh business object -->
       <bean id="livroQuantBo" class="br.com.spring.bo.LivroQuantBoImpl" >
            <property name="livroQuantDao" ref="livroQuantDao" />
       </bean>

       <!-- ProductQoh Data Access Object -->
       <bean id="livroQuantDao" class="br.com.spring.dao.LivroQuantDaoImpl" >
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
       </bean>

     <!-- PROXY -->

       <bean id="livroBoProxy"
            class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="target" ref="livroBo" />
            <property name="interceptorNames">
                <list>
                    <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
                </list>
            </property>
       </bean>

        <bean id="livroQuantBoProxy"
            class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
            <property name="target" ref="livroQuantBo" />
            <property name="interceptorNames">
                <list>
                    <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
                </list>
            </property>
       </bean>
```

And it's doing this runtime exception:

```
 Hibernate: select livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id as quantidade1_2_, livroquant0_.quantidade as quantidade2_, livroquant0_.livro_id as livro3_2_ from springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro livroquant0_ where livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: select livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id as quantidade1_3_, livroquant0_.quantidade as quantidade3_, livroquant0_.livro_id as livro3_3_ from springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro livroquant0_ where livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: select livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id as quantidade1_3_, livroquant0_.quantidade as quantidade3_, livroquant0_.livro_id as livro3_3_ from springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro livroquant0_ where livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: select livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id as quantidade1_2_, livroquant0_.quantidade as quantidade2_, livroquant0_.livro_id as livro3_2_ from springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro livroquant0_ where livroquant0_.quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade=?, livro_id=? where quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade=?, livro_id=? where quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade=?, livro_id=? where quantidade_livro_id=?
 Hibernate: update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade=?, livro_id=? where quantidade_livro_id=?
 Nov 6, 2012 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 40001
 Nov 6, 2012 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 SEVERE: Batch entry 0 update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade='0', livro_id='1' where quantidade_livro_id='5' was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
 Nov 6, 2012 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 WARNING: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 40001
 Nov 6, 2012 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
 SEVERE: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
 Nov 6, 2012 3:02:49 PM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
 SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
 org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
     at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:82)
     at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
     at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:254)
     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:142)
     at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
     at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
     at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
     at $Proxy0.transacao(Unknown Source)
     at br.com.spring.service.Servico.executa(Servico.java:29)
     at br.com.spring.service.Servico.run(Servico.java:19)
  Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade='0', livro_id='1' where quantidade_livro_id='5' was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2621)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1837)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2754)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:247)
... 17 more
   org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [update springhibernate2.quantidadeLivro set quantidade=?, livro_id=? where quantidade_livro_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this below link for the subject **12.2.2. Serializable Isolation Level**

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/transaction-iso.html