# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException

Tags: java, hibernate

I know this question asked lot of times on Stackoverflow but I'm looking for how does it happen in my code? Where should I look for change in my code.

*Ignore variable declaration of sessionFactory and Hibernate configuration I know how to create database connection.*

```
public void callMethod(MyClass m){
    MyClass updatedMyClass = MyMethod(m);
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(updatedMyClass);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}

public MyClass MyMethod(MyClass m){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    MyClass objMyClass = (MyClass) session.get(MyClass.class, m.getId());
    .....
    objMyClass.setSomething(...);
    .....
    session.close();
    return objMyClass;
}
```

I'm interested in...

- Why this is happening?
- `Session.get` uses which lock mode?
- `session.close()` release all lock for that database connection session?

Reference: [org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException - Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097957/org-hibernate-exception-lockacquisitionexception-threads)